# Check port status on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, port

I have a CentOS machine, and I opened a port on witch I should get a stream (actually it is the 5004 port - rtp). However, seems like the stream is not received.

Is there anyway to check on status of a port? (I mean not on/of... but if anything is received).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use `netstat` to see state of port.

Second, you can use `tcpdump` to see traffic going in and out on that port.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 "port 5004"
```

reports traffic on `eth0` to port 5004.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `lsof -i :5004` to see if any process has that port open. Alternately, if you're not sure about the port in use but do know the process that is listening, you can use `lsof -p process_id` to find the port.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted; I still believe it is worth checking if the port is in use by the expected program. If it is, then moving on to tcpdump is appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Check 'iptables -L' for any rule blocking port 5004 and turn off firewall and selinux in 'system-config-securitylevel'